# Which is better of the two: if-elif-else or if-else

Tags: java, coding-style, if-statement

This is not a homework question, this question is a result of just another discussion with my friend.

I searched a lot but could not find any reliable source which establishes the answer with proper reasoning so here I am at the mecca of programmers.

Which of the following two ways of coding is better:

```
if(a)
{
    if(b)
    ....
    else if(c)
    ....
}
```

or

```
if(a && b)
...
else if(a && c)
...
```

I searched and found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity to be useful but still could not make out final choice.

Please provide relevant reasoning as well.

Cheers!

Comment: By performance point of view; You will hardly get any significant performance improvement from using any of them over the other one. IMHO, It's just a readability thing, you should care about. Nothing else.

Comment: please replace the '&' by '&&', or did you really mean '&'? you also may add a tag about the used programming lanuage

Comment: @vlad_tepesch changed the question abit, if you could please take a look again.

Answer (score 2):

I think without optimization first method should be faster.

Since in 1st method  you check `a` **once** and then its `b` or `c`. if b is `false` then there are 3 checks(comparisons).

But in the second you check `a`  **twice** if `b` is `false`(once if `b` is `true`). There will be 4 checks if `b` is false. but the compiler will probably optimize both to be the same.

Comment: I think (assuming `a` is a boolean, not a function) that this is a perfect example of a *micro*-optimization, most likely giving *no* noticeable performance improvement for any non-trivial program. It's more about the [tag:coding-style].

Answer (score 1):

obsolete due to question changes

that may not be the same since the if(b) block may change the a.

If all variables in the conditions are constant then the compiler may output the same code to avoid the additional *and* operation of the second variant.

The additional & is also the reason why i would prefer the first variant.

Comment: he adapted the question, my answer is obsolete now

Answer (score 1):

In my coding experience, it depends on the content of the dots. If just a single or few lines of code, I prefer the 2nd. However, if there're more, I'll use 1st block.

Answer (score 0):

The first one possibly makes fewer comparison since it compares a only once, but the second one always compares a twice and b and c once

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if (a) ... then if b... You can think of it as distribution.. a*b + a*c = a*(b+c) or tree building. yes - no - no, yes - no - yes and so on. You know your logic is good when you can build easily that three otherwise you must rethink your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Almost they are not Difference in time order or any thinks.
Difference between them is completely relation to your architect of your code and your vision.for example if condition of A is repeater i suggest first way,else i prefer a simple code  like as second way because this is easy for read and continues.and other development is More enthusiastic to help you.